# Find the sum of an infinite series if it converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

How would I go about finding the sum of the following infinite series?

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+2+3+4+..+n}$

I'm assuming a limit of some sort. I apologize if this is trivial, I am not that great at math.

Comment: $1+2+\cdots+n=\frac12n(n+1)$

Comment: I think that The sum is  $1$

Comment: This is the same as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{n(n+1)}$

Comment: @TsemoAristide:  it can't be because the first term is $1$.

Comment: It's $2{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Answer (score 3):

From all the information in the comments:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+2+3+4+\cdots+n}$$
$$= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)}$$
$$=2  \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$
$$=2  \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)$$

and now you can use telescoping series to finish.

Answer (score 1):

${1\over{n(n+1)}}={1\over n}-{1\over{n+1}}$

$S_n=2-{1\over {n+1}}$

Answer (score 1):

This is equal to 
$$2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$
because $\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{i(i+1)}{2}$.

$\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ can be written as its partial fraction decomposition $\frac{a}{n} + \frac{b}{n+1}$, such that $an+a+bn = 1$. Let $a=1$ and $b=-1$. 
$$2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1} = 2(1-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} \ldots) = 2(1) = 2$$
(This is a telescoping series)